# Access files from one cpanel account to another

Tags: permissions, symlink, cpanel

I have a server which has CloudLinux installed with cpanel and whm.

On this server I have 2 cPanel accounts, ABC1 and ABC2.

I want ABC2 to access files in ABC1?

I created a link using SSH WinSCP, which I am assuming creates a Symbolic link to the folder. After doing this and when using SFTP protocol, I can access the shortcut folder (ABC1) using the ABC2 account, as I said, this is working only when using SFTP.

But I want it to work for FTP, since I am assuming that it would then work also for scripts (as that has been my primary intention from the beginning).

This is what the FTP program (FileZilla) say when attempting to access the shortcut folder:

> Response: 550 Can't open ASD1: No such file or directory
>
> Error:    Critical file transfer error

**OS:**
Linux server.domain.com 2.6.32-604.30.3.lve1.3.63.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Sep 27 06:34:10 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: have you tried making a hard link ?

Comment: @mazs I did, but I got the error `Hard link not allowed`

Comment: Sorry, my bad didn't read it carefully. Folders cannot be hard-linked.

Comment: if you have cagefs enabled, disable it, or exclude those account from it